# Does the getFromClipboard function work on macs?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Looking for a yes or no.

If the answer is no, then looking for some ideas to do the same thing on a mac.

To note - The last posts I saw on google dealt with Office 2004, I'm on 2016 as are the mac users I'd be hoping to build this code for :)

This is the code in question.

```
Set objClipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
objClipboard.GetFromClipboard

On Error Resume Next 'Turns Error checking off
vClipArray = Split(objClipboard.GetText(1), vbCrLf)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then         'Script will error if there is no copy, etc..
    MsgBox "Bad Copy, Sorry"
    End
End If
On Error GoTo HandleErrors 'Turns Error Checking on
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But there's a weird problem with the function, which is discussed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/read-clipboard-contents-in-vba-excel-for-mac-not/4485ab02-dced-4bf2-853d-fc667f5782a8?auth=1). Simply, it sets the clipboard text but **also** usually adds some random trailing characters. E.g., a clipboard value of "hey" will give you "heyT<". One of the users reported the issue to MS.

It's quite interesting. I played around with a few variations of the code. It's possible to get CONSISTENT random characters. But **in**consistent random characters is more useful to us... I added a loop, see code below. It repeats the faulty command 1000 times and saves the *shortest* resulting version of the string.

For debug purposes, if you run this as is, the first MsgBox gives you the initial result (which may or may not be successful - notice it often has junk characters) and the second MsgBox displays the shortest text, which should be correct.

Perhaps we could run some analysis to determine a more reasonable number than 1000.

Another method would be to compare strings and find at what point the characters start to differ.

```
Sub GetClipBoardText2()
    Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim str1 As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

    clipboard.GetFromClipboard
    str1 = clipboard.GetText

    MsgBox str1, vbOKOnly, "FIRST RESULT"

    'Determine shortest result of 1000 attempts:
    strLenMin = 0
    For i = 0 To 1000
        str1 = clipboard.GetText
        strLen = Len(str1)
        If strLenMin = 0 Then 'nothing stored yet
            strBest = str1
            strLenMin = strLen
        Else 'compare length to that of the shortest stored string
            If strLen < strLenMin Then 'it's smaller, store it
                strBest = str1
                strLenMin = strLen
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox strBest, vkOKOnly, "SHORTEST RESULT"

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         MsgBox "Bad Copy, Sorry"
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```